# Adding a default for a parameter query in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, parameters, ms-access-2007, default

I have a report query that asks users for two parameters.  One of these parameters is a date.  Is it possible to have a non-answer (i.e., the user presses the "`OK`" button without having entered a date) default to `Today()`?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution:

Set `[What is the date?]` as the first criteria, and `Date()` as the second (Or) criteria!

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.  By using an or here, it will show both things on the current date and things that are in the answer.  The other answer by Judah is far superior.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are not using a form for entering your criteria,

In your query try this as the Criteria for the date field:

```
IIf(IsNull([What Is The Date?]),Date(),[What Is The Date?])
```

Comment: I tried this and an inverse version (i.e., `IIf([What is the date?]>0, [What is the date?], Date())`).  I also tried listing `[What is the date?]` on the first criteria line and `IIf(IsNull([What is the date?]), Date())` as an or criteria within the design view.  Every version I tried (including multiple IIF statements and multiple criteria lines) resulted in an empty dataset.

Comment: Does your date field have time values in them as well?  Is there a value with today's date?  If you just put `Date()` as the criteria, do you get anything?

Comment: please post your comment as an answer!  I had been trying to do the IIF statement, but simplifying the alternate criteria to just `Date()` did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with Judah's solution is that it will always bring up items that meet the default value even when you enter a different one.

Try using the "Nz" function instead. For example, I entered the following into my "Criteria:" field:

```
Nz([Enter Date:], Date())
```

If the user enters a date, it uses that date. If the user doesn't, it uses today's date.

Hope that helps.